# executeCommand liquibase,relative path and user feedback

Tags: java, shell, liquibase

For a research subject, I need to know if some people/companies use Liquibase to manage "other things" than database.

For example, to migrate some data from an existing database. We are several developers, each one with one database for test on our local machine. From time to time, we need to update all the data from our database, or add some existing from the production server to run some test.
Right now, we extract them in a JAR, and we run those JAR manually. We would like to automatize this action, by writing in our xml some command. For example :

```
    <changeSet id="2013-08-06_refactorProjectTable" author="morgan">
        <comment>A</comment>
        <executeCommand executable="java">
            <arg value="-jar"/>
            <arg value="/home/etiik/Bureau/SRMvision/integration-1.6-refactorProjectTable.jar"/>
        </executeCommand>
     </changeSet>
```

The question we ask ourself is if some people already did it, and if it's viable or not ?!
Moreover, I could need some help about the absolute path here. As I told before, it's on our local machine ..So it's not really helpful like this. I would like to know if it was possible to use it as for the , which is a relative path.
Actually, if I try to do the same way, it fails at deploy (when I run pwd in this executeCommand, I see that I'm in the config folder of my glassfish domain!)

Thanks for your help! :)
Best Regards,

Morgan

Comment: I used liquibase in several projects but never had the need or idea to do this - I think this is not the right tool for your needs!

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if many people use Liquibase in this way. Ideally you would build the above task into a different part of your execution environment. With popular systems like Ant or Maven, you can set something like that to be run every time you run a certain command such as liquibase:update or liquibase:rollback.

The execution environment should set a current directory. In Maven, it will only consider files from its local root, which is really useful because you can shuffle the code and project around any way you want it. The downside is that the liquibase maven plugin is a little bit unforgiving. It is unclear whether blame lies with maven or with the plugin, but that is something to keep in mind. I spent a day or two fighting with it.

Just so you know, I work at a mid-size startup in NYC as a software engineer if that is useful for your research.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but after playing around it looks like you can run an executable relative to the liquibase jar file, e.g.

```
<changeSet id="OU" author="mathew">
        <executeCommand executable="{liquibase.jar dir}../bin/update-scripts/some.sh" />
    </changeSet>
```